# Angular 2+ with Knockout

Tags: angular, knockout.js, single-page-application, boilerplatejs, crossroadsjs

As being a Backend Developer myself, I have been maintaining a Knockout SPA project for about a few months which is built on Boilerplate.js where the routing is handled by Crossroads.js.
And I would like to gradually migrate to Angular 2+ if possible.

Training myself and improving my skills on Angular 2+ sounds like a better plan. However I have quite a few things which I can not foresee myself, so I felt like asking these questions to public for any feedback you could provide.

- Has anyone used Angular 2(+) with Knockout before? Since ng-controller etc got removed along the way to Angular 2, is it still possible to get those two libraries working?
- Is it possible to replace Angular routing with any other routing libraries?
- Since I have Crossroads handling the routing for me with the current setup, is it possible to get the routing lib working in collaboration with Angular routing?
- If I can find a way to replace Crossroads or Angular routing, I am thinking of wrapping every single module inside an Angular Component to consume the functions etc. Is it a good practise or what would your approach be in this case?

I would really appreciate any suggestions, guidelines or tutorials if there are any.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Angular 2+ has all of the features knockout has. Ideally you would want to just go full angular.

Comment: @JohnPavek I would like to migrate my application module by module since it is not a personal project but an enterprise application already in use and being developed still. 
Moving to Angular 2+ at once is my last choice for now :)

Comment: it's been awhile, but what did you end up doing?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my notice @JasonlPrice I have forgotten about this post.
What I did was quite easy to be honest.
I am running KO and NG together in the same application for about a year now, migrating slowly.

Simply placed my <ng-app></ng-app> tags in my index.html which then is replaced by the router-outlet rendering my NG components.

To be able to get the routing working I did some tricks an started all routes with "ng-" etc.